# react-google-maps-api documentation is not accessible

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-google-maps-api

when I tried to access the documentation , giving below error
[404 not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TbGU.png)

I cleared all my cache still giving same error.
There no other documentation avaialable.
https://react-google-maps-api-docs.netlify.app/ :- this is documentation link
whenever I tried to access it is giving 404 error

Comment: Check here - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-google-maps/api

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Temporary workaround: ↓ (copy of 1st of July)
https://web.archive.org/web/20230701010714mp_/https://react-google-maps-api-docs.netlify.app/#section-introduction
**BEWARE** as instructed in Slack by the lib owner **DO NOT ENTER YOUR Google Maps API Key** as it could eat your budget. I would personally just use it as reference until the official docs are back (not sure if my current Map implementation with this lib is purging the budget, so track yours carefully).

P.S
I've joined their Slack and the owners seems to be aware of this problem, but have no time fixing it. Hopefully a contributor will find & fix the issue. We can only wait for the official fix.